# Why did I get "Undefined" message?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

I have defined a object in a js file:

**myobj.js**

```
MyObj={
  test: {
     startTest: function(){
         var x = SOME_PROCESS_A;
         var y = SOME_PROCESS_B;
         return {x: x, y: y};
     }
  }
}
```

In another js file I call this object function:

**other.js**

```
var mytest = MyObj.test.startTest
var a = mytest.x;
var b = mytest.y;
```

my index.html:

```
<body>
 <script src="myobj.js"></script>
 <script src="other.js"></script>
</body>
```

I got the error from firebug in **other.js**, "`mytest`" is **undfined** in the line "`var a = mytest.x;`" Why??

Thank you,all. I got another "undefined" problem in the similar code, please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700054/variable-is-not-defined-error-why)

Comment: you should use it like a function: var mytest = MyObj.test.startTest()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to do

```
var mytest = MyObj.test.startTest(); //calls the function and returns the value to mytest
```

and not

```
var mytest = MyObj.test.startTest;//assigns the function to mytest
```

Comment: Thank you. but I got another undefined error, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700054/variable-is-not-defined-error-why

Comment: @Mellon, you shouldn't post a new question. It will likely be closed as duplicate. Update this question

Answer (score 3):

You have forgot to call the function:

```
var mytest = MyObj.test.startTest()
```

Answer (score 1):

becouse mytest is a function object, and there are no properties defined in it.

you can either call it like

```
MyObj.test.startTest();
```

or rewrite your object something like:

```
MyObj={
  test: {
     startTest: function(){
         this.x = SOME_PROCESS_A;
         this.y = SOME_PROCESS_B;
         return {x: this.x, y: this.y};
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: *"becouse mytest is a function object, it doesn't have properties"* Functions do have properties, and you can even add your own. Specifically in this case, though, this particular function doesn't have the `x` and `y` properties.

Comment: yes I meant this particular function. I will correct my answer, thanks ;)

Comment: Thank you, but I got another undefined error, here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700054/variable-is-not-defined-error-why