# Variable "is not defined" message, why

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have defined a object in a js file:

**myobj.js**

```
MyObj={
  
  test: {
     value: {a: 10, b: 7},

     startTest: function(){
         var x = this.value.a;
         var y = this.value.b;
         return {x: x, y: y};
     }
  }
}
```

In another js file I call this object function:

**other.js**

```
mytest = MyObj.test.startTest //assign starTest function to mytest
var a = mytest().x;
var b = mytest().y;
```

my index.html:

```
<body>
 <script src="myobj.js"></script>
 <script src="other.js"></script>
</body>
```

I got the error from Firebug in **myobj.js**:

> "`this.value`" is **not defined** in the
> line "`this.value.a;`"

Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why I got "Undefined" error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699861/why-i-got-undefined-error)

Comment: No, it's different from my previous post

Comment: This is personal preference: I don't like how you declare MyObj. I prefer "function MyObj(){ [...] }". Same for the startTest inner function: I Prefer "this.startTest = function(){ [...] }". Those are more "standard" ways. Refer to this StackOverflow question with a really good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript

Comment: Don't create a new question. Instead, update your original question with all the information. I mean obviously the code you posted there was not complete, otherwise you would have not get another error...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mytest = MyObj.test.startTest`

This gives you a function without context. If you call this function directly then `this` is `window`.

You want to all `test.startTest()` so that `this` is `test`

[An excellent guide on `this`](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this)